# Is it possible for mrna vaccines to affect DNA?

Tags: vaccines, dna

https://www.forbes.com/sites/victoriaforster/2021/01/11/covid-19-vaccines-cant-alter-your-dna-heres-why/

In this article on Forbes it is claimed that mrna vaccines can't in any way affect DNA.
Does this go against new research on reverse transcription?

Comment: Is the question whether it can or whether it does?

Comment: The latter implies the former anyway .

Comment: but the former does not imply the latter. There are infinite things we *don't* know about molecular biology (or any other field), so how could we prove that it's never ever possible?

Comment: If you read the question you see it doesn't have to as far as this question goes, that is also quite obvious.

Comment: Focus on what you can prove then.

Comment: well the question says "does it go against new research?" which is pretty vague. Can you be more specific?

Comment: https://sciencewithdrdoug.com/2021/02/15/breaking-study-sheds-more-light-on-whether-an-rna-vaccine-can-permanently-alter-dna/

Comment: This is just an example, the research description is vague precisely because of the non specificificity of the research and the fact that the posibility of general reverse transcription is well known

Comment: that article specifically says "they did not find full-length viral RNA integrated into genomic DNA" and "I am not making the claim that an mRNA vaccine will permanently alter your genomic DNA."  in other words, it's a troll post meant to get clicks to his blog

Comment: related, can someone write a question  about whether SARS-CoV-2 changes your DNA permanently?

Comment: Don't get your point but the link is also constituting the research I mean in the q

Comment: I don't have to say why I am skeptical about the claim, and I think that stating the impossibility of something in such a young field is quite dubious in and of itself.

Comment: Perhaps this question is more suitable to [Biology SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @bradbury9 https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/98164/3126